# How do I downgrade my current socketio installation?

Tags: npm, socket.io

I'm running Socketio 3.04 but I need to get an older version 2.x.
How can I do that from npm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On terminal: `npm i socket.io@<wanted version>` (for example: `npm i socket.io@2.0.1`)

Or:

You can change the version directly on the `package.json` file, and then on terminal: `npm i`.